# How to say "after all" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-comparison

Wiktionary says *"after all"* is a prepositional phrase. It shows these three words: *denique*, *demum*, *tandem*

The English-Latin dictionary I have says it's an adverbial phrase. It shows these other three words: *tamen*, *quamquam* and *saltem*.

The problem is that I think I can literally translate *"after all"* as *"post omnia"* into Latin, like this example:

> I'm ok after all I've been through

because those translations don't seem to fit in Latin.

What would be the better word?

Comment: Which meaning of "after all" are you trying to convey? It can be used as an idiom, but also for its literal meaning ("after all these things"), and the translation will be different.

Comment: The literal meaning.  I'm able to understand the others meanings if I read them with time.

Comment: Since an adverbial phrase is one that functions as an adverb and a prepositional phrase is one that consists of a preposition and its object, the two are not mutually exclusive.  For example, consider "those translations don't seem to fit in Latin," where the phrase "in Latin" is both adverbial and prepositional.

Comment: You've mis-parsed the English. "after" modifies "all I've been through" as a clause; "after all" is not itself a clause (in that sentence). It's like asking what the translation of "me the" is, in the sentence "pass me the salt".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you gave, you'd probably have a past participle instead of using *post*, though you could have that, too.

> passus omnia mala valeo.

Cf. Propertius 2.8.35:

> omnia formosam propter Briseida passus
> Having suffered everything on account of beautiful Briseis

You could also make it into a relative clause:

> Qui omnia mala passus sum, valeo.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is the literal meaning ("after everything"), then the literal translation is appropriate. In other words, if you want to say someone is exhausted *after everything* she's experienced, then she would indeed be *fessus post omnia* (perhaps with a noun to make explicit what exactly left her so tired).

The other translations you're finding are for the idiomatic meaning (a special sort of emphasis). If you want to say someone speaks French because he *is* from France, after all, then *post omnia* is not a good translation. Is he from France only after a certain point? What point is that? This is where those other translations come in.